# Can I use excel add-ins on iphone? on android?

Tags: office-js

I've tried using excel add-ins on Mac and office online on My Mac, both works well. But I can't find the add-in entrance on excel for iphone, as well as the office online opened on an iphone.

In [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins#client-requirements-non-windows-smartphone-and-tablet) I find a description about running add-ins on iphone. So have anyone succeed in using excel add-ins on iphone? Besides, what about on andriod?

On office for Mac and office online, the add-in button is in the insert menu:

[image]

but on iphone, there is no add-in button
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Excel add-ins can be used in the Excel app on iOS if the developer has opted to support iOS as a platform. 
You can see the list of "Products Supported" for each add-in if you open the add-in listing page on AppSource.

Android OS is currently supported only for Outlook add-ins.

Updated to add; add-ins can be added via the add-in menu in the insert ribbon in Excel on iOS
[image]

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of the add-in button on excel for iphone? I still haven't found the add-in button. On office for Mac and office online, the add-in button is in the insert menu, but on iphone, there is no such a button. I've inserted the screenshot in my question.